# Creating an entity in a background thread in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using MagicalRecord and am trying to create an entity in a background thread then use it in the main thread. This is the code I have:

```
var localRecipe: Recipe?
MagicalRecord.save({ (localContext : NSManagedObjectContext!) in
    localRecipe = Recipe.createEntity()
    localRecipe?.name = "HiHi"

    }, completion: { (success : Bool, error : Error?) in

        print(localRecipe?.name)
        let recipe = localRecipe?.mr_(in: NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default())
        print(recipe?.name)
})
```

When I try to retrieve *localRecipe* in the main context the object does not exist in the persistent store. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `Recipe.createEntity()` is creating the `Recipe` in the default context.

You should be using the `localContext` provided in the block to create your `Recipe` entity. e.g:
`localRecipe = Recipe.createEntityInContext(localContext)`

Then when the `localContext` is saved it should be merged into the main context, `NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default()`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the only issue.  Let me know how you go.

Comment: That was it! Thank you.

Comment: Woohoo! No problem :)